# Try to get a Value from a Json String

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I wrote a app that converts XML to Json, I try to get the value "content" from the Json, but i can't get it.
I only get the full file,i can't reach the value "content" that gives me the Price value that i needed.

Here is the Code part

```
                //From XML to Json
                JSONObject xmlToJson = XML.toJSONObject(result);
                //Get the Json from result
                JSONObject jsonObject = xmlToJson.getJSONObject("result");
                Log.i("ergebniss",jsonObject.toString());
                //Get the value plz (Works)
                String json1 = jsonObject.getString("plz");
                //Give it out to TextView
                xmltojson.setText(json1.toString());
```

This is the JSON string i get

```
{
   "result":{
      "plz":87484,
      "taxRate":19,
      "deliveries":{
         "delivery":{
            "unloadingPoints":1,
            "litre":1000,
            "price":{
               "oilGrade":"Heizöl Standard Schwefelarm",
               "orderLink":"https://www.heizoel24.de/.../1/1000/1/24,9,11,5,6/67,78",
               "content":"67,78"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please can any one  help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `xmlToJson.getJSONObject("price");` ? At the 2nd line of code.

Comment: Yes it returns nothing .

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.get(map, path).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Jackson jar API in your app to convert xml into json format. It first bind the data directly to a java object. It creates an instance of XMLMapper and with the help of its readValue method, it reads the content of xml file. 
  It writes down the content in JSON format with the help of ObjectMapper class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Jackson.

```xml
<!--Converted xml from json-->
<root>
   <result>
      <deliveries>
         <delivery>
            <litre>1000</litre>
            <price>
               <content>67,78</content>
               <oilGrade>Heizöl Standard Schwefelarm</oilGrade>
               <orderLink>https://www.heizoel24.de/.../1/1000/1/24,9,11,5,6/67,78</orderLink>
            </price>
            <unloadingPoints>1</unloadingPoints>
         </delivery>
      </deliveries>
      <plz>87484</plz>
      <taxRate>19</taxRate>
   </result>
</root>
```

First, convert XML into JSON and then get the specific child by reading each sub-JsonNodes from converted JSON.

```java
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(xml.getBytes());
        JsonNode price = new ObjectMapper()
                .valueToTree(jsonNode)
                .get("result")
                .get("deliveries")
                .get("delivery")
                .get("price");

        String content = price.get("content").asText(); // 67,78
```

jackson depencies

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: When i debug it , it stops at "delivery" and returns a Exception e

Comment: What exception is it throwing? I've exected on machine & working pretty well

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: It seems like Json data may not contains the given keys. Can you check what json data is coming from the URL?

Comment: {"plz":"87484","taxRate":"19","deliveries":{"delivery":{"unloadingPoints":"1","litre":"1000","price":{"oilGrade":"Heizöl Standard Schwefelarm","orderLink":"https://www.heizoel24.de/bestellung/8","":"67,78"}}}}

Comment: See that JSON you mentioned in question has the base object called `result` but here there was nothing like result object. and also make sure to always keep the `content` value under the `price` object. and try the below code for given JSON from above.

````java
 JsonNode price = new ObjectMapper()
                .valueToTree(jsonNode)
                .get("deliveries")
                .get("delivery")
                .get("price");

        String content = price.get("content").asText();
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and it´s working !

```
   try {
                jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(s);                               // XML to Json
                JSONObject result1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("result");        // gets top level object
                JSONObject deliveries = result1.getJSONObject("deliveries"); // get deliveries "collection" (Not a collection in this case)
                JSONObject delivery = deliveries.getJSONObject("delivery"); // get price object (both properties and content)
                JSONObject priceObj = delivery.getJSONObject("price");      // get price object (both properties and content)
                String oilGrade = priceObj.getString("oilGrade");           // get the oilGrade
                String price = priceObj.getString("content");               // get the price

                afterValue = price.replace(',', '.');                       //replace the , with an . to work with a double .
                double priceDouble = Double.parseDouble(afterValue);        //parse the String to a Double
```